# Let $A_n$ be a sequence with $A_0 = A_1 = 1$ and $A_n = 2^{A_{n-2}} + 2^{A_{n-1}}$ for $n\ge2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $A_n$ be a sequence with $A_0 = A_1 = 1$ and $A_n = 2^{A_{n-2}} + 2^{A_{n-1}}$ for $n\ge2$. Prove that there is no $n$ such that $A_n$ is divisible by $99$.

I'm not quite sure how to get started on this and it doesn't seem like these is an easy way to get induction to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there is an $n$ such that $99 \mid A_n = 2^{A_{n-2}} ( 1 + 2^{A_{n-1} - A_{n-2}})$.

What does this imply?

> The remainders $ 2^k \pmod{99}$ are $ 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 29, 58, 17, 34, 68, 37, 74, 49, 98, 97, 95, 91, 83, 67, 35, 70, 41, 82, 65, 31, 62, 25, 50, 1, \ldots$.
>  This means that $A_{n-1} - A_{n-2} \equiv 15 \pmod{30}$.

Why can't this happen?

> For $n \geq 4$, both of these terms are even, so their difference is even.

It remains to check that $99 \not \mid A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$, which is obvious.

Comment: Can you clarify why the first statement implies that $A_{n-1} - A_{n-2} \equiv 15 \pmod{30}$?

Comment: Consider the remainders of $2^k \pmod{99}$. Note that $ 2^{30} \equiv 1$ and $ 2^{15} \equiv -1$.